# Manipulating Switch Gyro controls with a mouse via USB Gadget

Tags: python, controller, hid, raspberry-pi4, gyroscope

Maybe I'm looking at this from the wrong angle, but I found code from a [Japanese blog](https://github.com/Bokuchin/SwitchProconGyroMouse) that translates the pro controller's gyro controls on switch to a mouse. One problem with this is that the Procontroller still sends it's gyro position through the USB Gadget `/dev/hidg0`. I was wondering if there was a viable option for being able to take the `HIDraw` output and map it to a mouse/keyboard without the controller actively sending a signal to through `hidg0`. Obviously I'll keep poking around until I figure something out, just wondering if anyone else has attempted something like this before

I was able to translate most of the comments in the code and get a basic understanding of what the code is doing, but any time I think I'm onto something the program terminates.

I've found that `mouse_int[0]` is left middle and right click. `mouse_int[2]` & `mouse_int[3]` are the sensor's x and y movements.

so far my search has lead me to a [reverse engineering](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Nintendo_Switch_Reverse_Engineering) mock up of a Procontroller and lots of fumbling around with HID documentation, granted I think the reverse engineering was most of the work needed.

```
#assign gadget, procon and mouse to their respective devices
##terminal 'lsusb' to find serial
##ex: Bus 001 Device 021: ID ***057e***:2009 Nintendo Co., Ltd Switch Pro Controller
gadget = os.open('/dev/hidg0', os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK) #hidg0 is our device outputting as Procon
procon = os.open('/dev/hidraw3', os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK) #terminal: sudo dmesg | grep -A7 057e
mouse  = os.open('/dev/hidraw4', os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK) #terminal: sudo dmesg | grep -A7 046d
                                                            #046d is Logitech's G502 HERO mouse
mouse_int = bytes([0,0,0,0])
'''
mouse_int[0] = left, middle, right clicks
mouse_int[2] = sensor
'''
```

I've started questioning if I even need to read the mouse as an `hidraw` and mabye using `import keyboard` or `pyautogui` But most of what I'm doing is dissecting what each piece of code does so I can manipulate what I'm wanting

This is the portion of code they used to adjust gyro controls with the mouse sensor

```
'''something to do with mouse sensor, translated "If you don't put a
    lot into sensor you'll run out'''
    if mouse_int[1] != 0:
        b = 127
    else:
        b=0
    if mouse_int[2] != 0:
        b = 127
    else:
        b = 0
    d = bytes([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    ac0 = bytes([255]) if output_data[14] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[14] + b])
    ac1 = bytes([255]) if output_data[16] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[16] + b])
    ac2 = bytes([255]) if output_data[18] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[18] + b])
    ac0_1 = bytes([255]) if output_data[26] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[26] + b])
    ac1_1 = bytes([255]) if output_data[28] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[28] + b])
    ac2_1 = bytes([255]) if output_data[30] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[30] + b])
    ac0_2 = bytes([255]) if output_data[38] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[38] + b])
    ac1_2 = bytes([255]) if output_data[40] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[40] + b])
    ac2_2 = bytes([255]) if output_data[42] + b > 255 else bytes([output_data[42] + b])
    
    #changes mouse movement to gyro
    gy0_0 = convert(output_data[19:21], mouse_int[1:2], 250, False)#
    gy1_0 = convert(output_data[21:23], mouse_int[2:3], 250, False)#
    gy2_0 = convert(output_data[23:25], mouse_int[2:3], 0, False)#

    gy0_1 = convert(output_data[31:33], mouse_int[1:2], 250, False)#
    gy1_1 = convert(output_data[33:35], mouse_int[2:3], 250, False)#
    gy2_1 = convert(output_data[35:37], mouse_int[2:3], 0, False)#

    gy0_2 = convert(output_data[43:45], mouse_int[1:2], 250, False)#
    gy1_2 = convert(output_data[45:47], mouse_int[2:3], 250, False)#
    gy2_2 = convert(output_data[47:49], mouse_int[2:3], 0, False)#

    e = a+output_data[13:14]+ac0+output_data[15:16]+ac1+output_data[17:18]+ac2 \
        +gy0_0+gy1_0+gy2_0 \
        +output_data[25:26]+ac0_1+output_data[27:28]+ac1_1+output_data[29:30]+ac2_1 \
        +gy0_1+gy1_1+gy2_1 \
        +output_data[37:38]+ac0_2+output_data[39:40]+ac1_2+output_data[41:42]+ac2_2 \
        +gy0_2+gy1_2+gy2_2 \
        +d

    #print(int.from_bytes(gy1_0, byteorder='little'))
    #print(mouse_int[1])
    return e
```

This looks to be what's writing to the gadget aka `/dev/hidg0`. Unfortunately for me it doesn't overwrite the actual controller in any way

```
def procon_output():
    global mouse_int
    while True:
        try:
            output_data = os.read(procon, 128)
            #output_mouse = os.read(mouse, 128)
            #print('<<<', output_data.hex())
            #print(output_data)
            e = replace_mouse(output_data, mouse_int)
            #print(e.hex())
            os.write(gadget, e)#output_data
            mouse_int = bytes([0,0,0,0])
        except BlockingIOError:
            pass
        except Exception as g:
            print(type(g))
            print(g)
            os._exit(1)
```

Comment: Found this github  project
https://github.com/mzyy94/nscon
It's in golang, so I'm significantly less familiar with it, but it doesn't require a controller to be connected at all, ie. no interference.


Few issues I've encountered with the source code:
• Inputs being held trigger more than once
• It doesn't like taking multiple inputs at a time. If you're holding a button and try to input a second button, then the first one will be cancelled out.
• Not exactly sure how to implement gyro still
• Haven't been able to map `&con.Input.Stick.Left | &con.Input.Stick.Right`